# How to view previous Firefox notifications?

Tags: firefox, notifications

I got a message notification from Firefox, but it wasn't on the screen for long. I'd like to read what it said again. How do I view previous notifications?

Comment: yes, I just missed my notifications as it is so fast, and seemingly no way to revisit them:   https://www.reddit.com/r/PushBullet/comments/1uwd1c/is_there_a_notification_history_in_firefox/

Comment: At this moment this is not possible natively. If someone wrote an extension that could manage the incoming notifications it would be possible. So far I do not know of any extensions that can do this.

Answer (score 2):

The Firefox extension [Service Worker Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/service-worker-control) has a companion extension called [Service Worker Control - Push Notification History](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/swcontrol-notification-history).

Using a pair of add-ons to achieve this probably isn't ideal, but they're both tiny at 9.48KB and 22.33KB respectively, and they do work smoothly. One was last updated a month ago, the other 2 months ago.

---

#### Method

The best way to install add-ons is always from within the Firefox browser itself, where you can select the 'Add-ons' option from the Firefox menu, which opens an 'Add-ons Manger' tab.
Search for them by name at the top of the tab and, once located in search results, add-ons can be installed by clicking the blue 'Add to Firefox' button, followed by clicking 'Allow' on the subsequent security warning.

For these particular add-ons further configuration is necessary: within the Add-ons Manager click the three dots to the right of the Service Worker Control add-on, select Options, and then check the 'Enable push notification history' checkbox.
A list of push notifications will now be available in the Firefox toolbar, and also from within the Service Worker Control addon Options.

Comment: Please explain briefly how the user can use these add-ons to achieve the desired effect. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @G-Man Good idea, have added some directions. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of these add-ons have been pulled from the firefox store. I'm searching for another way.

Comment: I down voted this answer since the suggested extensions no longer exist.

Comment: 0 results found for "service worker control"

Answer (score 1):

see, and support if possible, this bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1854263 .

Answer (score -6):

I presume you are talking about desktop notifications. 
For Windows 10:

You can click "Action Center" icon in the taskbar or press WIN+A - this will display all notifications that you haven't dismissed or clicked on (ie. took the recommended action, say from antivirus, etc).

If you did interact with notifications, they are gone from the action center but you might be able to access some of the data if you know which app pushed the notification through the event viewer, tho it's not a real backup of notifications, but it might help.

Comment: Definitely says "Firefox notifications" up there. These are a.k.a. [Web Push Notifications](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, seems that Firefox "Web Push Notifications" don't show up with the regular desktop notifications

Comment: @AaronWallentine, https://superuser.com/a/1809292/904401

Comment: Actually things like this might work if your Firefox sends its notifcations elsewhere. I'm using MX linux and kept getting these mysterious notifications on my desktop that disappear after about a couple seconds or when clicked, some of which are Firefox Web Push Notifications. Just now, I clicked the little bell on the panel at the bottom of the screen and went into "Notification Settings" and it says it gets notifications from various applications including Firefox. I went under "log", toggled the switch to on, and set it to log notifications always from all applications. It logs VLCs now.

Comment: I'll have to wait to see if it logs the next Firefox one.

Comment: Oh, I see: irvnriir and RokeJulianLockhart are pointing out that Firefox is supposed to send send its notifications to Windows's centralized notification system too. It just actually works on my MX Linux, but didn't on AaronWallentine's Windows.